# issue with oplog collection to copy mongodb to postgresql using mosql

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-replication

I'm reading `mosql` code and how it uses `oplog` collection from `mongodb` to copy to `postgresql`.

For updating case, for example:

I saw that `mosql` always update the whole document to `postgresql` instead of only the modified fields. That is really weird because there is not sense to update all the fields in `postgresql` table when I want to update only 1 or 2 fields. That is a problem because I'm using bigger documents.

Looking the code I saw that `mosql` uses the `o` field from `oplog` but it keeps the whole document and that is why `mosql` update all the fields in `postgresql` and there is not way to know what fields were updated.

Is there a way to figure out what fields were updated? to updating only that fields instead of the complete document?